# get images from SD card - android

Tags: android, image, sd-card

my path is /sdcard/newfolder/ which contains images.
how do I  display images from newfolder in grid view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html